# Dual copy of tikz packages cause update problem in texlive

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texlive

I recently updated texlive to 2015 (at least, my texlive mangager shows 2015). I use \pgfversion to check, and it shows 2.10. Then I use texlive manager to update pgf, it looks that it works, I should update to 3.0.1a,

[image]

But I try \pgfversion again, still got 2.10 and the library which is supposed in pgf 3 doesn't work...

How to really update my pgf version ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Use `kpsewhich` or `\listfiles` to see if you have another copy somewhere e.g. if you have more than one distribution of TeX installed or stale files in your personal tree or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr, I found that I had another old copy of tikz in my user directory...You are kind of right.

Comment: @JP-Ellis, I solved my problem. See the edited question.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include answers to them. The site works best when the answer space is used for answers and the question space for questions. If comments answer your question, you can ask one of those who commented to write an answer which you can accept. If you solve a problem independently, you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: @JP-Ellis, I am not sure if it is the same question to the one you mention. Maybe this one can be helpful to someone with the same problem like me...

Comment: @zljt3216 I'm glad you found a solution to your question; however, as cfr mentioned, we try and avoid having answers edited into the question and instead, ask that you post that edit as an answer instead.  This will make it easier for people to find this issue if they have the same problem.

Comment: @JP-Ellis, I have put edited the question to original form and gave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was caused by another old copy of Ti*k*Z. Specifically, I installed TeXLive 2014 at `C:\texlive`, but there is a folder called `C:\Users\<username>\texmf\tex\latex` where I had put user-defined library or templates.

I think sometimes ago, when I first try to use Ti*k*Z, I downloaded the old Ti*k*Z there (because I didn't know TeXLive already included it). It seemed that this user path has higher priority than the installation one. After deleting Ti*k*Z in the user path, everything worked again.

So from this, my recommendation is that if you want to install some library, you'd better check TeXLive manager first.  There might be already something you want, and you can just update there instead of downloading by yourself and cause some inconsistency problem like mine.